# can i access a Custom Property for a term set inside my Search Serivce Query Builder

Tags: 2013, development, search, search-results, administration

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection. and we need to implement an expiry policy for the wiki pages, so if the wiki page is set to be expired or a it is linked to a certain term , then to exclude the wiki page from search. currently i have the following :-

- Each wiki page is linked to a Managed Metadata column. and this column can have values such as `"Project1","Project2","Project3"`.

[image]

- Also each wiki page is linked to an "Expiry Status" column which have 2 values; `Yes`,`No (default)`.
- now the idea of implementing the expiry policy, is that if the wiki page has its "Expiry Status" = `Yes`, or its Project is expired to exclude the wiki page from the search.

so not sure how i can implement this inside sharepoint , till now i achieve the following :-

1. i created a new site column named "Expiry Status" , and then inside the **Central Administration >> Search Service >> Result Source**, i define to exclude any wiki page which have Expiry Status  = `Yes`, as follow:

[image]

2. now for the managed metadata column , i define a Custom Property for all the terms including; Project 1, Project 2, Project 3 named "Show In Search" with default value = `true`. and users can chnage the value to "`No`".

[image]

3. but i am not sure if i can modify the Result Source inside the Search Service, to exclude from the search any wiki page which is linked to a term and this term have its custom property named "Show In Search" = No ? is this possible ?

so can anyone adivce on this ? or there is a better way to implement my requirement  ?

**EDIT**

Now i tried the following steps but they did not work.

1) I went to the term store , and i click on certain terms, add a new shared property named "ShowInSearch" with two values either;`false` or `true`. as shown below:-

[image]

2) then i went to the "central administration" >> "managed services" >> "Result Sources" , then i modify the query using the query builder where i added the following `{Term.ShowInSearch}<>"false"` to exclude pages linked with a term  property named "ShowInSearch" with value = `false` , as follow:-

```
{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople} {Term.ShowInSearch}<>"false"
```

Then i run a full scan, but the search will always show the following error:-

> Nothing here matches your search

so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Comment: can anyone advice on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions.

> if i can modify the Result Source inside the Search Service, to exclude from the search any wiki page which is linked to a term and this term have its custom property named "Show In Search"

According to the article [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx), it is possible to use custom property associated with a term, if you use [managed metadata driven navigation](http://sp2013.blogspot.no/2012/07/metadata-driven-navigation.html). 
Extract from the article below.

**{Term.property} Any property from the property bag of the term, including custom properties.**

Now on using this query variables from Result source or Search Webpart, I tried this in Search webpart and you can check if the Result source one works.

> so can anyone adivce on this ? or there is a better way to implement my requirement ?

Another way to implement this is to use managed metadata driven navigation and then in the page use a Search/Content Search web part with following query for example.

**{Term.property}:"true"**

Comment: thanks for your reply and the links you provide ... but can you please check my edit , as i tried your appraoch but it did not work ...

Comment: can you check my edit please ?